# In polymer.js how to pass argument to a function?

Tags: polymer

In polymer.js, I want to bind both function and some parameters to a click event, like this:

```
<template repeat="{{i in List}}">
<button on-click="{{click-func(i)}}">
</template>
```

With click-func defined below:

```
click-func: function(i){
   do something; 
}
```

How to make the above code work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to do it is assign the value you wish to send as a generic attribute and pick it up using the sender value sent with the click / tap event.

```
<template repeat="{{i in List}}">
  <button on-click="{{click-func}}" dataItem="{{i}}">
</template>
```

function

```
click-func: function(event, detail, sender){
  var dataItem = sender.attributes.dataItem.value;
  // do something with dataItem; 
}
```

edit: kind of confused title says JS but tag says dart. this answer is good for polymer JS.